# Redis sentinel can not run in k8s with environment variables in config file

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I try to run a redis sentinel in k8s pod and it show:

```
        *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 27
>>> 'sentinel monitor mymaster $REDIS_MASTER_IP 6379 2'
Can't resolve master instance hostname.
```

the line 27 of config file is:

```
sentinel monitor mymaster $REDIS_MASTER_IP 6379 2
```

The value of this variable is the svc name ('alink-redis') for this deployment.
When I use `echo $REDIS_MASTER_IP` it can print `alink-redis`.
I can `ping alink-redis` and get the ip of svc.

If I try to change `$REDIS_MASTER_IP` to `alink-redis` in config file.
Then the sentinel can run.

So why and if it could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

OK.
I have get the answer for developer.
Config file not support environment variables.